# When extracting smaller classes from a larger class, at what point do the smaller classes become their own units that should be tested as such?

Tags: unit-testing, refactoring

I keep hearing conflicting ideas:
that unit tests should have no dependencies and create mocks
and that they shouldn't care about implementation details/structure

but if I extract a smaller class out of a larger one, it becomes a dependency. and if I test that independently, its testing + "locking in" the structure. If I test it via the larger class, its integration testing.

Answer (score 0):

To me if we follow TDD, that is red, green, refactor.

1. Red: Each requirement is getting translated into a failed test case case
2. Green: we write only the code that is required to pass the failing test case
3. Refactor" Here we refactor any possibilities to make things better.

We continue this cycle until all those smaller pieces of requirements got converted into Unit Test Cases

While refactoring my requirement is not changing, I would keep my test case as it is. In some cases I would move the test cases from previous class to new test classes based on where they are applicable.

For further reading I would recommend Clare Sudbery's article on

[Refactoring: This class is too large](https://martinfowler.com/articles/class-too-large.html)